# Passing environment envariables inside webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

What I want to achieve is to set an BACKEND environment variable so our VueJS project will send request to the API of that host however it always return `Unexpected token :`.

Below is the current code of our `config/dev.env.js` and I'm a little stuck now

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  HOST: process.env.BACKEND,
  NAME: '"Jaguar Dashboard"'
}
```

I just want the process.env.BACKEND to have a value like 'http://example.com' and then our VueJS project will now start nicely. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

It is working when I do it like this:

`module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  HOST: 'http://example-0e1b-4a12-91ef-b853a47bab34.node.dockerapp.io:8000',
  NAME: 'Jaguar Dashboard'
})`

When I try `JSON.stringify(process.env)`, the error(`Unexpected identifier`) shows in this line:

`eval("var merge = __webpack_require__(424)\nvar prodEnv = __webpack_require__(69)\n\nmodule.exports = merge(prodEnv, {\n  NODE_ENV: '\"development\"',\n  HOST: JSON.stringify(__webpack_require__.i({\"NODE_ENV\":\"development\",\"HOST\":\"http://example-0e1b-4a12-91ef-b853a47bab34.node.dockerapp.io:8000\",\"NAME\":Jaguar Dashboard}).BACKEND),\n  NAME: 'Jaguar Dashboard'\n})\n\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///258\n");`

When I try `'"'+process.env.BACKEND+'"'`, the error(`Unexpected identifier`) shows in this line:

`eval("var merge = __webpack_require__(424)\nvar prodEnv = __webpack_require__(69)\n\nmodule.exports = merge(prodEnv, {\n  NODE_ENV: '\"development\"',\n  HOST: '\"'+__webpack_require__.i({\"NODE_ENV\":\"development\",\"HOST\":\"http://example-0e1b-4a12-91ef-b853a47bab34.node.dockerapp.io:8000\",\"NAME\":Jaguar Dashboard}).BACKEND+'\"',\n  NAME: 'Jaguar Dashboard'\n})\n\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///258\n");`

But for my successful code where I just defined a string, it shows the code below on that line:

`eval("var merge = __webpack_require__(424)\nvar prodEnv = __webpack_require__(69)\n\nmodule.exports = merge(prodEnv, {\n  NODE_ENV: '\"development\"',\n  HOST: 'http://example-0e1b-4a12-91ef-b853a47bab34.node.dockerapp.io:8000',\n  NAME: 'Jaguar Dashboard'\n})\n\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///258\n");`

**SCREENSHOTS OF THE CODES**:

`config/dev.env.js`
[image]

`build/webpack.base.conf.js`
[image]

`build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
[image]

P.S.

All of these response happens when I `npm run dev` in our VueJS project

Comment: have you declared `process.env.BACKEND` anywhere? also is there any need to add single & double quotes together?

Comment: I actually have no idea sorry, but when I try to do `console.log(typeof(process.env.BACKEND))`; It is indeed a string

Comment: try by removing the the single quote from `'"development"',` & `'"Jaguar Dashboard"'`

Comment: Same result....

Comment: can you share the entire config code

Comment: The one in the question is already it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last edit: you're trying to access `process.env` but have defined no ENV variable name (like `.BACKEND`); is it simply a typo or is that the source of the issue here? : )
Because this definitely works:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            BACKEND: JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND),
```

Edit:

What helped in the end was a variable value not wrapped in double quotes:

```
NAME: 'Our site'

// should have been:
NAME: '"Our site"'
```

Comment: I defined it as a LINUX environment envariable like `export BACKEND=example.com`

Comment: That works fine. But you also need to point your `JSON.stringify` call to that variable: `process.env.BACKEND` (instead of `process.env`, which you are doing atm I believe).

Comment: Sorry, but to be honest, I'm a little bit lost now, maybe putting some screenshots regarding the webpack config will help

Comment: I just added pictures on the question

Comment: Your `NAME` variable's value isn't wrapped in double quotes (only singles quotes are used atm).

Comment: GUESS WHAT! it was fixed! because of that :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that the strings are wrapped in another pair of quotes. This is so strings aren't inserted as variables.

From the DefinePlugin [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

> Note that because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value
>   given to it must include actual quotes inside of the string itself.
>   Typically, this is done either with either alternate quotes, such as
>   '"production"', or by using JSON.stringify('production').

You can do `HOST: '"'+process.env.BACKEND+'"'`

or

`HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND)` (more readable)

Comment: Sadly, it still did not work.. But I did an update on my question, regarding your suggestions.